what is this cable called on a 2003 chevy cavalier

What is the name of this cable that runs from the throttle to that black box? It seems to keep the car at an idle. The other cable runs to the throttle pedal that you push to give it gas.

At first glance, this cable connects to the cruise control actuator (number 1 below), which is partially hidden by the bracket (number 2 below) attaching it to the structure of the vehicle. Simple terminology would be that it is the cruise control actuator cable, while the site linked states it is the cruise control cable.
This is confirmed at gmpartsclub website (among many others) even though the module displayed on the linked site is of a different appearance. I believe this is due to the drawing on the site showing the module and the bracket as separate components. Image from linked site:

